# Adding local minio host to 'mc' configuration. Failed to add temporary MinIO server. MinIO is already stopped. How to fix it?

Tags: docker-compose, minio

I want to run min.io using bitnami/minio docker image. But I encountered "Adding local minio host to 'mc' configuration. Failed to add temporary MinIO server. MinIO is already stopped" in container logs.

Here is my docker compose file

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
   minio:
    image: bitnami/minio:latest
   ports:
      - '9000:9000'
      - '9001:9001'
   environment:
      - MINIO_ROOT_USER='test'
      - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD='test'
      - MINIO_DEFAULT_BUCKETS=my-first-bucket
   volumes:
      - 'data:/bitnami/minio/data'

volumes:
  data:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this issue."MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD" should be more than 8 characters.